# Zk support in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, zk

Is there any support of [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) in IntelliJ IDEA? If there is, how can I create a zk project in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not as far as I know. If you look through the IntelliJ's YouTrack there is an open [feature request for ZK support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61007). But even though it has quite a lot of votes the last activity is from a year ago.

There is also no plugin available in unofficial IntelliJ plugin repositories.

Comment: Thanks. It's so bad :(

Comment: I feel your pain. My worst nightmare is having to work with a technology which is not supported in IntelliJ (ie. having to use Eclipse) :)

Comment: So am I. I am going to fight with eclipse :)

Answer (score 3):

I released a ZK IntelliJ plugin in a bleeding edge version [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7855).
It can now support Zul editor with content assistant and syntax checking features.

Hope that it may help you to develop with ZK Framework.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to do some stuffs with it as soon as possible :-)